# How to create effecient stack implementation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a good stack implementation in JS. Pref jquery

Please help

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use an Array, as it contains the methods push and pop. If required you could write a wrapper around it to hide the fact it is an array.